# testing wrapped $http angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

I am using angularjs and i have to test wrapped $http

```
ang.factory("HttpService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
return {
get: function (url) {
  var result = $q.defer();
  $http.get(url).success(function ($data) {
    result.resolve($data);
  }).error(function ($data) {
    result.reject($data);
  });
  return result.promise;
}
 };
}]);
```

And i think test should be something like

```
beforeEach(module('ngBoilerplate.employee', function ($provide) {
  HttpService = jasmine.createSpyObj("HttpService", ["get", "post"]);

  $provide.value("HttpService", HttpService);
}));  

beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _HttpService_) {
  $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  HttpService = _HttpService_;
  $controller = _$controller_('EmployeeCtrl', {$scope: $scope, HttpService: HttpService});
}));
```

PS: I am using ngBoilerplate.
Thanks

Comment: OK but what's your question?

Comment: how to test httpservice

Comment: Note that you could simply write your function as `var f = function(response) { return response.data; }; return $http.get(url).then(f, f);`

Comment: To test your service, use the mock $httpBackend: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: That's why i wrapped http to avoid using httpBackend. Now i am doing it    with:
   it("should do something", function () {
      var vacationData = {
        "fromDate": 1,
        "toDate": 2,
        "description": "descr"
      };
      HttpService.post("somurl", vacationData);

      expect(HttpService.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("somurl", vacationData);
    });


and it seems to be working. 

...can't mark the code as code.